# Need advice how to re-open this question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, on-hold

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524211/

I don't understand the motivation behind people closin the question here.

I described my problem, I specified every tools' pros and cons and reasoning, I need advice on how to solve a **clear defined**, not Googleable problem. what's wrong with that?

Comment: Meh, it's a resource request, no matter how well you have researched it.  We have a close reason specifically designed for resource requests.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How exactly it's different from rampant jQuery questions on Stackoverflow? People need tools to solve problems.

Comment: Most of the jQuery questions are about how to do something in jQuery.  The ones asking for jQuery plugin recommendations get closed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why can't I close your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417553/software-pattern-for-auto-discovery-mechanism) ?

Comment: I've moved your question to Programmers, where it is a better fit.  Hopefully it will get some decent attention over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voted to reopen your question. It's valid and you have done your research.

Comment: Of course, the last sentence 'what are my **best** options' makes it opinion based. Therefore I vote for cl... erm.... just kidding. ;-) Today I saw so many crap questions, so a question like this is a real relief.